# Inverse Laplace Transform With Dead Time

Tags: laplace-transform

Here is the transfer function that needs to be transformed back into the time domain:

$$Y(s)=\frac{K_{2}e^{-\theta s}}{s(\tau_{1} s + 1)(\tau_{2} s + 1)}$$

Then would the response be:
$$y(t) = K_{2}(t-\theta ) \Bigg(1-\frac{\tau_{1}e^{\frac{-(t-\theta)}{\tau_{1}}}-\tau_{2}e^{\frac{-(t-\theta)}{\tau_{2}}}}{\tau_{1}-\tau_{2}}\Bigg)$$

EDIT:

Ok, I'm pretty sure I am right now, but how the hell do I put something like this into matlab?

Comment: $\mathcal L (u_c(t)g(t))=e^{-cs}\mathcal L(g(t+c))$

Comment: @Chilango Hey can you please check my answer and see if it makes sens, thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(e^{-\theta s}) = \delta(t-\theta)$$ also known as the Dirac Delta function. The rest is pretty easy to solve as it appears to be a second order of a Type 1 oscillator.

Comment: Almost forgot,
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}( K_{2}/s) = K_{2}u(t) = K_{2}, t \geq 0$$

Comment: hey can you please check my answer, (edited in original)

Comment: $\mathcal L$ is $not$ multiplicative. What is true is that $\mathcal L(f*g)=\mathcal L f\mathcal Lg$ where * is convolution. For your problem, use decomposition and the formula I posted above.

Comment: @Chilango Hi, can you please see my amended answer and let me know its correct or not, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using fraction decomposition? Seems easier to use instead of these hyperbolic functions that you've included. Chilango and I think that would be easier to do. I'm assuming $\tau$ is a time constant for your circuit or spring system.

Comment: I would complete the square in the denominator and use fractional deconpositon. For this, you need to have some information about $\zeta$ and $\tau$. Are they $>0$? Are they related? Etc.

Comment: @Chilango sure, the system can be looked at as two first order systems together, so we could write the transfer function as: $$Y(s)=\frac{K_{2}e^{-\theta s}}{s(\tau_{1} s + 1)(\tau_{2} s + 1)}$$

Comment: @Chilango Also, I have written an alternative solution in my original post, please have a look.

Comment: what happened to $\zeta$?

Comment: Well, before I wrote $\zeta$ because it was a general second order system however when I write it specifically as the product of two transfer functions I can write it as above. $$s(\tau^2s^2+2\zeta\tau s + 1)=s(\tau_{1} s + 1)(\tau_{2} s + 1)$$ So: $$\zeta= \frac{\tau_{1}+\tau_{2}}{2\sqrt{\tau_{1} \tau_{2}}}$$ and $$\tau^2 = \tau_{1} \cdot \tau_{2}$$ @Chilango

Comment: OK so write $Y(s)=K_2e^{-\theta s}\left ( \frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{\tau_1s+1}+\frac{C}{\tau_2s+1} \right )$, find $A,B,C$ and use the appropriate formulas to extract $y(t)$.

Comment: @Chilango I had already done that, please see my edit in the original post

Comment: @Chilango Am I to assume my solution is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38159/discussion-between-mathsishard-and-chilango).